# How should I combine multiple columns and convert to rows?

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I'm working on a table like the one below, and the table name is information:

```
-------------------------------
|id | gender | country |  age | 
-------------------------------
| 1 |    F   | America |  18  |
-------------------------------
| 2 |    M   | America |  22  |
-------------------------------
| 3 |    M   |  Japan  |  30  |
-------------------------------
| 4 |    M   |  Brazil |  32  |
-------------------------------
| 5 |    F   |  Norway |  34  |
-------------------------------
| 7 |    M   | America |  32  |
-------------------------------
|10 |    F   |  Norway |  22  |
-------------------------------
|13 |    F   |  Japan  |  36  |
-------------------------------
|14 |    F   |  Brazil |  19  |
-------------------------------
|25 |    F   |  Japan  |  33  |
-------------------------------
```

And I want the output to be:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| country |  total | Female | Male | 18 - 25 | 26 -35 |
------------------------------------------------------
| America |   3    |   1    |  2   |    2    |   1    |
------------------------------------------------------
|  Japan  |   3    |   2    |  1   |    0    |   3    |
------------------------------------------------------
|  Brazil |   2    |   1    |  1   |    1    |   1    |
------------------------------------------------------
|  Norway |   2    |   2    |  0   |    1    |   1    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

The following is my approach, first count the distinct id group by country and gender:

```
SELECT country, gender, COUNT(DISTINCT id)  FROM information GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Then try to create the table with age range:

```
(SELECT '18-25' AS '18-25'
        SUM(CASE WHEN (AGE >=18 AND AGE<=25) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM FROM information)
UNION
(SELECT '26-35' AS '18-25'
        SUM(CASE WHEN (AGE >=26 AND AGE<=35) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM FROM information)
```

But I'm not sure how to combine them and covert the columns to rows. Could anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select country, count(*) as total,
       sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as num_female,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as num_male,
       sum(case when age >= 18 and age <= 25 then 1 else 0 end) as age_18_25,
       sum(case when age >= 26 and age <= 35 then 1 else 0 end) as age_26_35
from information
group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on Gordon's answer which I prefer, because it eliminates the need for an explicit `ELSE` case:

```sql
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 1 END) AS Female,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 1 END) AS Male,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 25 THEN 1 END) AS "18-25",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 26 AND 35 THEN 1 END) AS "26-35"
FROM information
GROUP BY
    country;
```

Less code = usually a better thing

Comment: I'v use `sum` like Gordon did for so long and never realize you can do `count` since it will just skip the null. thanks a lot :D

Comment: @T.Peter Actually, I'm surprised Gordon didn't post this version, and I his answer, as Gordon is usually the one with a bag of a thousand SQL tricks.